# Why do I get: cannot open file 'Documentation/workflow_accordion.html': No such file or directory

Tags: shinyapps, golem

I am trying to add the shiny app into golem structure. Therefore, everything that I am asking here should be in line with golem structure.

Here is the problem:

I cannot add my html into a module. And that is why I get the following error:

```
cannot open file 'www/workflow_accordion.html': No such file or directory
```

Here is the module I have added to app_ui (make sure you see the golem structure here https://engineering-shiny.org/golem.html )

```
#' mod_workflows_ui
#'
#' @description A shiny Module.
#'
#' @param id,input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'
#' @noRd 
#'
#' @importFrom shiny NS tagList 
mod_workflows_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  shiny::tabPanel(
    "Workflows", icon = icon("list"),
    div(
      class = "container",
      shinyLP::jumbotron(
        "Workflows",
        "How to use the Bioinformatics for the Bench apps to access specific datasets and answer biological questions",
        button = FALSE
      ),
      hr(),
      includeHTML("Documentation/workflow_accordion.html"),
      br(),
      br(),
      br()
    )
  )
  tags$footer(
    includeHTML("Documentation/footer.html")
  )
  
}

#' mod_workflows_server
#'
#' @noRd 
mod_workflows_server <- function(id){
  ns <- session$ns
}
```

This module is added into several parts as per golem structure:

1. in app_server script as `mod_workflows_ui("mod_workflows_ui_1")`
2. in 02_dev - in dev folder as - `golem::add_module(name = "workflow_app", with_test = TRUE)`

After that I call in the mod_tutorials in app_ui file like this:
`shiny::tabPanel("Workflow", icon = icon("graduation-cap"),mod_workflow_ui("mod_workflow_ui_1"))`,

And then I go int run_dev and just run the app.

Now the issue is that I get this error:

```
cannot open file 'Documentation/workflow_accordion.html': No such file or directory
```

What am I missing? Why does it do this and how I can solve it, I am open for other ways of solving this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have 2 html's that I deal with above.

I will take only one example, the 'footer.html' since it is a bit harder to deal but because this is the exact pattern I have applied for the other html file.

**But** firstly, I have tried several ideas:

```
1. includeHTML("www/footer.html") 
2. app_sys("app/www/footer.html")
```

Yet, none of these work. **Apparently html files aren't specific to golem, according to @Colin Fay, as he mentioned here: https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem/issues/890**
Actually tried all his ideas and still, it did not work.

**However,**

what I have done **was to take what was written in html and turn it into a module according to golem** structure:

```
#' mod_footer_ui UI Function
#'
#' @description A shiny Module.
#'
#' @param id,input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'
#' @noRd
#'
#' @importFrom shiny NS tagList
mod_footer_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$footer(
      HTML(
        r"(
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img padding: 10px 10px; height="150px" src="www/logo_v4.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Links</h4>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="http://goto.az/logo">goto.az/bftb</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://website/groups/430852910696122/">Workplace Group</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://website/sites/Bench/SitePages/Bench.aspx">Tutorial Recordings</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>About us</h4>
        landing page was built by my name and other people's name. Please contact us with suggestions.
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Support</h4>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="mailto:">Contact </a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:">Contact </a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:"></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>)
        )"

      )
    )
  )
}

#' mod_footer_server Server Functions
#'
#' @noRd
mod_footer_server <- function(id){
    ns <- session$ns

}
```

Then adding these modules to golem scripts found in :

1. 02_dev in dev folder as `golem::add_module(name = "footer_app", with_test = TRUE)`
2. app_server in R folder as `mod_footer_ui("mod_footer_ui_1")`
3. app_ui in R folder as `tags$footer(mod_footer_ui("mod_footer_ui_1"))`

Then run the script provided in golem `run_dev` and it works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

You must use app_sys to link your file:

`includeHTML(app_sys("app", "www", "hello.html"))`

When the application is launched, the path is evaluated in the context of the package and not in the context of the running application. Hence the need for a path to a package file.

I hope that's clear enough.
:)

Comment: it does not work